# PostgreSQL function definition "syntax error at or near +"

Tags: postgresql, functions

Suppose a simple query:

```
(SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM events e WHERE e.id < some_id) 
  + ((SELECT MIN(timestamp) FROM events e WHERE e.id > some_id) 
    - (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM events e WHERE e.id < some_id)) / 2
```

If `some_id` is the parameter, this finds the approximate timestamp based on some sequence of events (it takes the previous and following event and averages their timestamps).

This query works great, now I want to package it as a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION id_to_timestamp(integer) RETURNS timestamp with time zone AS
$BODY$
    (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM events e WHERE e.id < $1) 
      + ((SELECT MIN(timestamp) FROM events e WHERE e.id > $1) 
        - (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM events e WHERE e.id < $1)) / 2
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

This suddenly fails with message

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "+"
... events e WHERE e.id < $1) + ((SELECT...
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the `+` operator problematic?

(The actual identifiers are anonymized.)

Comment: As mentioned in Craig's answer, your original query as-written returns an error too, so I'm not sure what you mean by "This query works great"?

Comment: Yes that is the problem, `SELECT` is missing in both the query and the function definition.

Comment: How did it work great then? What did you mean by that?

Comment: It was a part of the SELECT clause in a larger select.

Comment: In which case I think the question needs to be 'put on hold' - it's kind of misleading as it stands and you've got your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `LANGUAGE sql` function must be a complete SQL statement (or more than one).

Yours is just an expression.

Just prepend `SELECT`, like you would when running it stand-alone.

```
$BODY$
SELECT (SELECT ...
```

The reason it complains at the `+` is that, surprisingly, it's legal to parenthesise a top-level query. This, for example, is a valid query:

```
regress=> (SELECT 1);
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

(I had no idea about that until your question, either, so thanks. I'm not even sure it's intentional...)

Note that you'd have got the same error if you ran your original query as-written, so I assume you'd prepended `SELECT` to it.

```
regress=> (SELECT 1) + (SELECT 2);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "+"
LINE 1: (SELECT 1) + (SELECT 2);
```

Comment: I guess it is intentional - it helps when mixing top level EXCEPT and UNION for example.